# combining elements in a list of lists in R

Tags: r, apply, paste

I have a list called `samples_ID` with 116 vectors, each vectors has three elements like these:

```
"11"         "GT20-16829" "S27"
```

I wanna keep the 116 vectors, but combine the elements to a single element like this

```
"11_GT20-16829_S27"
```

I tried something like this

```
samples_ID_ <- paste(samples_ID, collapse = "_")
```

it returns a single vector, below is just a part of it:

```
..._c(\"33\", \"GT20-16846\", \"S24\")_c(\"33\", \"GT20-18142\", \"S72\")_c(\"34\", \"GT20-16819\", \"S50\")_c...
```

What am I doing wrong?
Can you help me please?
Thanks

Comment: Just use `dput` and provide a sample of your data .. and suddenly other people will be able to help you ..

Comment: What about `lapply(samples_ID, paste, collapse="_")`

Comment: `lapply` would work, as well as `sapply` which will automatically coerce to a vector of length 116. The result of `lapply` usually needs a touch of `do.call(c, lapply(...))` to get a vector. There are also other ways of going about this, like `unlist`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another base R option using `paste`

```
do.call(paste, c(data.frame(t(list2DF(samples_ID))), sep = "_"))
```

or

```
do.call(paste, data.frame(do.call(rbind, samples_ID)), sep = "_"))
```

Answer (score 2):

A tidyverse option.

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)

map(samples_ID, ~ str_c(., collapse = '_'))

# [[1]]
# [1] "11_GT20-16829_S27"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "12_GT20-16830_S28"
```

Data

```
samples_ID <- list(c("11", "GT20-16829", "S27"), c("12", "GT20-16830", "S28"
))
```

Answer (score 1):

In `base R`, we can use `sapply`

```
sapply(samples_ID, paste, collapse="_")
```